# Emberjs: Use a checkbox to display data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a data table with checkbox selection. If an item in the table is checked I want to display that data in another part of the page. Seems like it should be simple but I can't seem to figure it out. I made a js

[JS Bin with data table example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/likakehahani/4/)

Here is the controllers/route

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  productLinks: function(){
        return this.get('content');
    }.property('model', 'isSelected'),

  selectedProduct: function(){
    var selectedProd = this.get('productLinks').filterBy('isSelected', true);
    return selectedProd[0];
  }.property('isSelected'),

  isSelected: null
});
```

I would like this to evolve to only allowing a single selection, but I'll address that once I can get the data to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the dependency (`property`) correctly. You have the computed property depending on the `isSelected` property on the controller itself. You need to make it dependent on the `isSelected` property on each member of `productLinks`, which you do with the `@each` syntax.

```
selectedProduct: function(){
    var selectedProd = this.get('productLinks').filterBy('isSelected', true);
    return selectedProd[0];
}.property('productLinks.@each.isSelected')
```

Comment: Great! Thanks alot, I knew it shouldn't be that hard

Comment: Technically speaking, you can elide the second argument to `filterBy`. But instead, you could just use `findBy` to find the first selected element, so the entire function body becomes just `return this.get('productLinks').findBy('isSelected');`.